# Access Field in JSON Data

Tags: python, json, python-2.6

I have an API response in the following JSON format. If I want to extract a field, such as geocode, how would I do so? Is it redundant to put the response in JSON? I get an error saying the list indices must be integers, not str. Thanks in advance, new to this.

I've tried:

```
import requests
import json

response = requests.get("https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active")

data = response.json()
json.loads(data['features']['id'][0]['properties'][0]['geocode'][0])
```

Below is JSON data:

```
{
    "@context": [
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geojson/geojson-ld/master/contexts/geojson-base.jsonld",
        {
            "wx": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#",
            "@vocab": "https://api.weather.gov/ontology#"
        }
    ],
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-2791383-2596094",
            "properties": {
                "@id": "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-2791383-2596094",
                "id": "NWS-IDP-PROD-2791383-2596094",
                "geocode": {
                    "UGC": [
                        "PZZ560"
                    ],
                    "SAME": [
                        "057560"
                    ]
                },
                "references": [
                    "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/NWS-IDP-PROD-2790941-2595876"
                ],
                "status": "Actual",
                "parameters": {
                    "NWSheadline": [
                        "SMALL CRAFT ADVISORY IN EFFECT"
                    ],
                    "eventEndingTime": [
                        "2018-04-26T21:00:00-07:00"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
    ],
    "title": "Current watches, warnings, and advisories"
}
```

Comment: why are you using `json.loads`? when `data` is already in JSON format, yes it is redundant

Comment: That's why I asked! It was an example I saw somewhere else. I was just trying different things. I get the same error using `data['features']['id'][0]['properties'][0]['geocode'][0]`

Comment: Are you still using Python 2.6? If so, you should mention it in your question **and** add a "python-2.6" tag.

Comment: The way you access keys in the `dict` doesn't match its structure.

Comment: Yes, I'm using 2.6.6

Comment: I get `TypeError:` **list** `indices must be integers or slices, not str` for the example *json* and that set of subscripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is in the hierarchy that you use here:

```
json.loads(data['features']['id'][0]['properties'][0]['geocode'][0])
```

Correct one would be:

```
json.loads(data['features'][0]['properties']['geocode'])
```

Comment: This works exactly. Why is 0 placed after features? Is features a list?

Comment: @kkd92 Yes, so that you know - when you see '{' as a value, this means that field hold an object as a value. And when you see '[' this means that field has an array as a value. And that's where you need to use index like '[0]'. With Object values you should use property/field name to retrieve specific value, like ['properties']. Let me know if you still have any questions.